# How to add an animation on hovering an element in Vue3?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, transition

I'd like to apply an animation on hovering the element. Maybe it's better to use Transition component nowdays. The animation would be very simple, a scaling from 1 to 1,5 keeping the element on the page. So I think the v-if directive doesn't work here. Do I need to change the state dinamically here on mouseover and out? The case is that I don't want the element to dissapear.

```js
<Transition name="bell" type="animation">
  <div class="bell-element"    
    @mouseover="showBell"
    @mouseout="hideBell"
    >
</Transition>
.bell-enter-active {
  animation: bounce-in 0.5s;
}
.bell-leave-active {
  animation: bounce-in 0.5s reverse;
}
@keyframes bounce-in {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.25);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not uncommon depending on the animation to have JavaScript assist and insert classes or custom styling to the specific element. In your case have your tried :hover :active? CSS covers a lot of the basic states.

Answer (score 1):

Vuejs transitions are good when you use v-if on components for other reason than animations. Here you can just use native html/css animation.

```css
.bell-element {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  
  transition-duration: 250ms;
}

.bell-element:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="bell-element"></div>
```